# Facebook Embed Video Directly Onto Timeline

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to embed a video directly onto the FaceBook timeline. Here are my metatags:

```
<head prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns# fb: http://ogp.me/ns/fb# video: http://ogp.me/ns/video#">
      <meta property="og:url"         content="THIS PAGE'S URL" /> 
      <meta property="og:video:url"         content="MP4 FILE" /> 
      <meta property="og:title"       content="Sample Movie 123" />
      <meta property="og:description"     content="Description">
      <meta property="fb:app_id"      content="APPID" /> 
      <meta property="og:type"        content="video.movie" /> 
      <meta property="og:image" content="IMAGE.png" />
      <meta property="og:video:type"       content="video/mp4"> 
      <meta property="og:video:width"      content="200"> 
      <meta property="og:video:height"     content="500">
</head>
```

**EDIT**

I also tried the following (a swf file):

```
<head>
    <meta property="og:type" content="movie" /> 
    <meta property="og:video:height" content="260" /> 
    <meta property="og:video:width" content="420" /> 
    <meta property="og:video:type" content="application/x-shockwave-flash" />
    <meta property="og:title" content="Demo Video" /> 
    <meta property="og:description" content="Video description." />
    <meta property="og:image" content="IMAGE" />
    <meta property="og:video" content="http://example.com/jwplayer/player.swf?file=filepath" /> 
</head>
```

This just creates a link to the webpage and doesn't actually embed the media onto the timelime.

All help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Are you supplying only an mp4 source? only SWF files can be embedded directly

Comment: @lgy I tried swf also and still not working (see edit)

Comment: What did the debugger show for the version which had an SWF attached? (because I've used jwplayer before in this exact way and it was OK)

Comment: Oh, actually, you don't have a HTTPS source, so it'll only embed that video for users using Facebook over HTTP, which is a very tiny minority - you need a `og:image:secure_url` as well